# Unity Remote 5 with Android problem : CommandInvokationFailure: Unity Remote requirements check failed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity-remote

I'm trying to use unity remote 5. Here is what I've done:

1. In File\Build Settings, Android is selected
2. In Edit\Project Settings\Editor, Device is set to 'Any Android Device'
3. In Edit\Preferences\External tools, everything in the Android section is ticked
4. I have installed the 'Android build support' module with the 'Android SDK & NDK Tools' + 'OpenJDK'
5. In android studio, in Configure\SDK manager\SDK Tools, the 'Google USB Driver' is well installed
6. On my phone, I have unlocked the Developer options and enabled the USB debugging
7. Of course, I have downloaded Unity Remote 5 on my phone and connected it to my computer using a usb cable

But now when I press play in Unity, I got an error message :

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unity Remote requirements check failed
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.2.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe forward tcp:7201 tcp:7201

stderr[
error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.ADB.RunInternal (System.String[] command, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.ADB.Run (System.String[] command, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.ADB.Run (System.String[] command, System.String errorMsg) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
```

Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Unity engine might sometimes be a little bit difficult to get working.

some suggestions :

- Change the cable (sometimes this is the main issue).
- Under *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> *External tools*, scroll down and untick and retick the squares (sometimes this also has fixed my issue)

  [image]
- If you have many versions of unity installed - if you are able to - delete them all and even from your program files (`C:/Programfiles/unity/hub/editor`) and reinstall Unity fresh. I've had to do this before with one of my devices because it was getting confused which tools to load because I had so many versions installed.
- If you are using a Samsung, install Samsung drivers.

Just know that you are not alone with this. Unity remote is very eccentric to get it to work. Sometimes it works today, but it won't work tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I've tried everything you suggested but unfortunaly it didn't work, which really piss me off because I really don't know where the error comes from. Anyway I'll keep searching. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

「Build Settings」 -> 「Player Settings」  ->  「Editor」  ->  「Device」  ->  「None」

Finished.

Comment: Yeah but now nobody can use Unity Remote. fgdsrtgtretassgfs